# Prove that there exist $2^{\aleph_{0}}$ well-orderings of the set of all natural numbers.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From Chapter 6 Hrbacek and Jech (Ordinal Numbers) Problem 1.3. I don't understand how to begin. Below is the only solution I could find online, but even then I still don't understand how they arrived with those figures.
[image]

Comment: How would a chapter and exercise number be helpful without the name of the reference?

Comment: Of course there are only $\aleph_1$ distinct *types* of well-orderings on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Any bijection of $\mathbb{N}$ can be declared an order isomorphism with another well-order (of type $\omega$), e.g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the usual order on $\Bbb N$, you can show there are at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ because you can break $\Bbb N$ into $\aleph_0$ pairs $(2n, 2n+1)$.  You can then invert each pair or not, which is $\aleph_0$ binary choices.  There are at most $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ because there are $\aleph_0$ choices for the first element of the well order, and again for the next, and so on.  If you know $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak c$ you are done.

Comment: I think your upper bound argument is kind of vague (and might give the misleading impression that the order type is necessarily $\omega$). A more simple way is just that the well orders are all subsets of $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen:  good point.  When I first read it I thought it claimed the well order was a set of pairs $(a,b)$ where $a\in \Bbb N$ and $b\in \Bbb N$ was the position of $a$ in the list, which again claims that the order type is $\omega$, but the well order can just be all the pairs $(a,b)$ where $a$ comes before $b$.